# JQ - Store and Update JSON Over Time

Tags: jq

I'm trying to read some JSON data from file and then, via a series of prompts in a shell script, *update* that JSON over time to eventually write it back to disk later.

I've come to the following where I first read the original JSON into an `UPDATED_JSON` variable and then mutate it over time.

```
UPDATED_JSON=$(
    cat ../some_file.json | jq
)

...

UPDATED_JSON=$(
    echo $UPDATED_JSON | jq -r '.topLevelObject.leafNode = false' 
    # note that `topLevelObject` is guaranteed to exist but `leafNode` might not, in which case I want to insert it
)

echo $UPDATED_JSON
```

However this outputs `parse error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 18629`.

I suspect it's something to do with `UPDATED_JSON` not being in a format jq can later process due to how I assigned it?

Also note that I'll again be using jq for updating the file on disk with the updated JSON.

Comment: Do you have a _small_ sample input file to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Why do you generate raw (`-r`) output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting is crucial in shell scripts. If you do not quote your parameters when expanding, word splitting and glob expansion is performed. You don't want that to happen here.

```
UPDATED_JSON=$(jq '.' ../some_file.json)

# ...

UPDATED_JSON=$(
    echo "$UPDATED_JSON" | jq -r '.topLevelObject.leafNode = false' 
)

echo "$UPDATED_JSON"
```

`echo` should be safe with JSON content in the variable, but you might want to consider replacing it with `printf '%s\n' "$UPDATE_JSON"` just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your response knittl. So yes, I did actually _need_ the `printf '%s\n'` in my code for it to work! Man, quotes in shell scripts are such a convoluted pain. Think I need to go back and properly understand them. Thanks very much for your help.